# Intersect in java.awt.geom.Area not working

Tags: java, geometry

I'm currently trying to calculate the intersection of 2 Path2D an in order to do so I'm using the following function:

```
*private boolean pathOverlaps(Path2D path1, Path2D path2) { 
        Area a1 = new Area(path1);
        Area a2 = new Area(path2);
        a1.intersect(a2);
        return !a1.isEmpty();   
    }*
```

This works for most of the cases but not in all... With these Path2D, that intersect it returns false and I have no idea why.
Below are the points of the 2 Path2D that when used in the pathOverlaps function return the unexpected result, they should intersect, but it returns otherwise...

**Path1:** 
80.19948186528497   -49.90291262135922
80.19948186528497   -48.0
82.14766839378238   -48.0
82.14766839378238   -48.0
82.14766839378238   8.135922330097088
80.19948186528497   8.135922330097088
80.19948186528497   10.038834951456312
80.19948186528497   10.038834951456312
65.880310880829 10.038834951456312
65.880310880829 10.990291262135925
64.9062176165803    10.990291262135925
64.9062176165803    10.990291262135925
64.9062176165803    46.19417475728156
62.95803108808289   46.19417475728156
62.95803108808289   48.09708737864078
62.95803108808289   48.09708737864078
-103.90414507772022 48.09708737864078
-103.90414507772022 46.19417475728156
-105.85233160621763 46.19417475728156
-105.85233160621763 46.19417475728156
-105.85233160621763 -48.0
-103.90414507772022 -48.0
-103.90414507772022 -49.90291262135922
-103.90414507772022 -49.90291262135922
-107.0  -52.5
-107.0  -52.5
-107.0  -50.5
-109.0  -50.5
-109.0  48.5
-109.0  48.5
-107.0  48.5
-107.0  50.5
64.3    50.5
64.3    50.5
64.3    48.5
66.3    48.5
66.3    11.5
66.3    11.5
67.3    11.5
67.3    10.5
82.0    10.5
82.0    10.5
82.0    8.5
84.0    8.5
84.0    -50.5
84.0    -50.5
82.0    -50.5
82.0    -52.5

**Path2:** 
82.10000000000001   -24-24.625
82.10000000000001   -24-24.01748677518613
81.60751322481389   -24-23.525
81.0    -24-23.525
80.39248677518613   -24-23.525
79.9    -24-24.01748677518613
79.9    -24-24.625
79.9    -24-25.232513224813875
80.39248677518613   -24-25.725
81.0    -24-25.725
81.60751322481389   -24-25.725
82.10000000000001   -24-25.232513224813875
82.10000000000001   -24-24.625

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Patricia, read your post and and tell us if you think you've provided enough infomation, such as how `intersect()` works internally. Anyhow, I advise you to use a debugger to see where the code goes away from your expectations.

Comment: Adding an illustration seems useful. Likely this is some kind of rounding effect or similar numeric issue. The second path in particular has several lines which almost or completely coincide; I'd guess that's part of the problem. Getting path intersections right is tricky, particularly with imprecise numerics. [CGAL Arrangements](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html#PartArrangements) with rational coordinates come to mind as a possibility for exact solutions, just to hint at how tricky this problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, turns out the scaling area that I am building is not the one I expected, I now have to work on that algorithm.